# Maximum non-overlapping intervals in a interval tree

Tags: algorithm, interval-tree

Given a list of intervals of time, I need to find the set of maximum non-overlapping intervals.

For example,

if we have the following intervals:

```
[0600, 0830], [0800, 0900], [0900, 1100], [0900, 1130], 
[1030, 1400], [1230, 1400]
```

Also it is given that time have to be in the range `[0000, 2400]`.

The maximum non-overlapping set of intervals is `[0600, 0830], [0900, 1130], [1230, 1400]`.

I understand that maximum set packing is NP-Complete. I want to confirm if my problem (with intervals containing only start and end time) is also NP-Complete.

And if so, is there a way to find an optimal solution in exponential time, but with smarter preprocessing and pruning data. Or if there is a relatively easy to implement fixed parameter tractable algorithm. I don't want to go for an approximation algorithm.

Comment: Does "maximum" mean the largest _number_ of intervals or the longest _total duration_ of intervals?  Your example solution is 3 intervals for a total duration of 6.5 hours.  What makes it maximal, the 3 or the 6.5?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is not a NP-Complete problem. I can think of an `O(n * log(n))` algorithm using dynamic programming to solve this problem.

Suppose we have n intervals. Suppose the given range is `S` (in your case, `S = [0000, 2400]`). Either suppose all intervals are within `S`, or eliminate all intervals not within `S` in linear time.

1. Pre-process:

   - Sort all intervals by their begin points. Suppose we get an array `A[n]` of n intervals.

     - This step takes `O(n * log(n))` time
   - For all end points of intervals, find the index of the smallest begin point that follows after it. Suppose we get an array `Next[n]` of `n` integers.

     - If such begin point does not exist for the end point of interval `i,` we may assign `n` to `Next[i]`.
     - We can do this in `O(n * log(n))` time by enumerating n end points of all intervals, and use a binary search to find the answer. Maybe there exists linear approach to solve this, but it doesn't matter, because the previous step already take `O(n * log(n))` time.
2. DP:

   - Suppose the maximum non-overlapping intervals in range `[A[i].begin, S.end]` is `f[i]`. Then `f[0]` is the answer we want.
   - Also suppose `f[n] = 0`;
   - State transition equation:

     - `f[i] = max{f[i+1], 1 + f[Next[i]]}`
   - It is quite obvious that the DP step take linear time.

The above solution is the one I come up with at the first glance of the problem. After that, I also think out a greedy approach which is simpler (but not faster in the sense of big O notation):

(With the same notation and assumptions as the DP approach above)

1. Pre-process: Sort all intervals by their **end** points. Suppose we get an array `B[n]` of n intervals.
2. Greedy:

   ```
   int ans = 0, cursor = S.begin;
   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
       if(B[i].begin >= cursor){
           ans++;
           cursor = B[i].end;
       }
   }
   ```

The above two solutions come out from my mind, but your problem is also referred as the **activity selection problem**, which can be found on Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_selection_problem.

Also, *Introduction to Algorithms* discusses this problem in depth in 16.1.

Comment: I'm a little confused on the second bullet of point 1. Are you saying we need to make a new array of the next possible interval? Is that what `Next[n]` is, or is `Next[n]==A[n]`? Perhaps you could write some more code to clarify?